# Populate list with tuples

Tags: python, bioinformatics, rosalind

I'm just fiddling with a simulation of ([Mendel's First Law of Inheritance](http://rosalind.info/problems/iprb/)).

Before i can let the critters mate and analyze the outcome, the population has to be generated, i.e., a list has to be filled with varying numbers of three different types of tuples without unpacking them.

While trying to get familiar with [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) (I'll need combinations later in the mating part), I came up with the following solution:

```
import itertools

k = 2
m = 3
n = 4

hd = ('A', 'A')       # homozygous dominant
het = ('A', 'a')      # heterozygous 
hr = ('a', 'a')       # homozygous recessive

fhd = itertools.repeat(hd, k)
fhet = itertools.repeat(het, m)
fhr = itertools.repeat(hr, n)

population = [x for x in fhd] + [x for x in fhet] + [x for x in fhr]
```

which would result in:

```
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'A'), ('A', 'a'), ('A', 'a'), ('A', 'a'), ('A', 'a'), ('A', 'a'), ('A', 'a'), ('A', 'a')]
```

Is there a more reasonable, pythonic or memory saving way to build the final list, e.g. without generating the lists of for the three types of individuals first?

Comment: What exactly is the output you are hoping for?

Comment: @cdhagmann Edited question, expected output is now included

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `itertools.chain` to combine the iterators:

```
population = list(itertools.chain(fhd, fhet, fhr))
```

Though I would say there's no need to use `itertools.repeat` when you could simply do `[hd] * k`. Indeed, I would approach this simulation as follows:

```
pops = (20, 30, 44)
alleles = (('A', 'A'), ('A', 'a'), ('a', 'a'))

population = [a for n, a in zip(pops, alleles) for _ in range(n)]
```

or perhaps

```
allele_freqs = ((20, ('A', 'A')),
                (30, ('A', 'a')),
                (44, ('a', 'a')))

population = [a for n, a in allele_freqs for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: Personally, I feel that using range is not very pythonic, but that's a pretty minor style issue

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: How is `range` not Pythonic?

Comment: like I said, it's a small thing, but seeing range always reminds me of Java and is less functional, but it's really a personal thing.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Amazing! I realize that i only touched the surface of list comprehensions so far. BTW, good that you used the term allel which i avoided in order not to frighten anybody ;)

Comment: @KlausWarzecha: Cool! Now that I think of it allele was actually the wrong term (since these are pairs of alleles), I should have used genotype. But I'm glad it answers your question.

Comment: +1, I just noticed this answer includes a mention of the one I provided.  I think it would have been even better to lead with it explicitly since it is a "more reasonable, pythonic or memory saving way to build the final list".

Answer (score 1):

This should work I suppose.

```
pops = [2,3,4]
alleles = [('A','A'), ('A', 'a'), ('a','a')]
out = [pop*[allele] for pop, allele in zip(pops,alleles)]
print [item for sublist in out for item in sublist]
```

I have put the code on [CodeBunk](http://codebunk.com/bunk#-Ix2sl_uPsDtELj8pXJ3) so you could run it too.

Answer (score 0):

```
population = 2*[('A', 'A')] + 3*[('A', 'a')] + 4*[('a', 'a')]
```

or

```
hd = ('A', 'A')       # homozygous dominant
het = ('A', 'a')      # heterozygous 
hr = ('a', 'a')       # homozygous recessive

population = 2*[hd] + 3*[het] + 4*[hr]
```